# NodeJS with Objection and Knex - Error: Unable to acquire a connection

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js, objection.js

I am setting up a project using Knex, Objection, Node and Typescript and when I tried to run a simple command like `knex --knexfile ./src/db/knexfile.ts  migrate:list --client pg`, I keep getting:

> Error: Unable to acquire a connection

I don't know why this is happening. Here is my knexfile:

```
export const config: { [key: string]: Knex.Config } = {
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      database: "tests",
      user: "postgres",
      password: "examplepassword"
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations",
      loadExtensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    acquireConnectionTimeout: 3000,
    ...knexSnakeCaseMappers,
  },
```

Here is my file used for the connection:

```
import Knex from 'knex';
import { Model } from 'objection';
import { config } from "./knexfile";

const db = Knex(config.development);
Model.knex(db);

export default db;
```

Now in my main server file (index.ts), I simply import the db file. My index.ts looks like this:

```
import express from "express";
import names from "./routes/Names";
import "../src/db/db";

const app = express();
  
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/names", names);
  
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("We are online!");
});
```

The migration I am trying to list or run is:

```
import { Knex } from "knex";
import { TABLE_NAMES } from "../../constants/tableNames";
//import "../db"; <--- importing the connection yields the same error!

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
    await knex.schema.createTable(TABLE_NAMES.Names, (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name', 255).notNullable();
        table.json('hobbies');
        table.string('email', 255).notNullable();
        table.timestamp('createdAt');
        table.timestamp('updatedAt');
    });
}


export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
    return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(TABLE_NAMES.Names);
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you running on localhost? on the default port? i dont see these specified in your connection config